# Bake lights (lamps) to vertex color

Tags: mesh, vertex-colors

Is it possible to somehow bake vertex colors from lamps?

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think you can directly, as far as I know, but what you could probably do instead is a multi-step process to achieve your desired final result.

You can only bake to a texture, so bake said lamp influence to an image based texture, then use said texture to create a new vertex color layer from it using an addon to translate from image to vertex colors.

Rough steps: Create your desired mesh, add a "neutral" material to it, like say a purely diffuse white material that will receive clean colors from lamps.

Unwrap said mesh to a new UV Map, create a new texture and bake that object to said texture.

Save the image, then use the addon [UV/Bake Texture to Vertex Colors](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/UV/Bake_Texture_to_Vertex_Colors) to create a new Vertex Color layer based on said texture.

Comment: Nice one! I didn't know about this add-on. Could definitely come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

There is a button 'to vertex color' in the baking panel. It does ehat you're after.

At least, its there in blender internal - not sure about cycles

Comment: Didn't know about that option. Nice find!

Answer (score 1):

Baking lights into Vertex color. Worth Gravedigging that thread as there's very little info about that.
For those interested:

- Render > Render Engine > Cycles
- Render > Bake > Influence > Lighting > Direct and Indirect
- Bake > Output > Active Color Attribute.

This way you can bake the lights that will influence your existing vertex color.

A very useful thing I was used to do in [3D-Coat](https://youtu.be/zHX9Xp3vYb8?si=Ch1l5x9F-e1Iuatk)  and I'm really glad it can be done in Blender too. Sadly Vertex Paint is a really bugged process in Blender (Ctrl+Z cannot be trusted at all). And the worse, it cannot as far as I know bake Curvature. Too bad really :/