# How to bake light into a model?

Tags: modeling

I'm making a building and baking AO into the texture.
I wonder if it's possible to place lights into the model, and baking them also into the texture?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82140/bake-lights-lamps-to-vertex-color/82153#82153

Comment: Whatever you bake, is just a texture, an image.  Though, you can use that texture, apply it onto a mesh and set the shader to Emission, for a lighting effect.